# Resolving hostname in uwsgi.ini internal routing

Tags: uwsgi

I have an uwsgi ini file that should redirect traffic to a different host.

```
[uwsgi]
route = .* http:somehost:8000
```

Unfortunately, the hostname somehost cannot be resolved by uwsgi. However, it is listed in /etc/hosts and dnsmasq is running.

Is there a way to configure uwsgi to use dnsmasq to resolve the name ?

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve domain name in config using `resolve` directive.
Here is how it worked out for me:

```
resolve = api_backend=api_backend

route = ^/api/ http:%(api_backend):9000
```